# What is the meaning of integrating over the state space?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, wavefunction, hilbert-space

If $\lvert\psi\rangle$ denotes the state space corresponding to a qubit, then what is the meaning of the $$\int d\psi$$ where the integral is over whole state space of a qubit? How do I evaluate it? Just below equation (1) of [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0205035), the author says we can use this integral to normalize.

Comment: ...the meaning of integrating over the state space is generically to "sum over all possibilities". Without telling us *what* is being integrated, there can't be an actual answer to this.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I was reading http://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0205035v2.pdf In the beginning (  just below equation (1) )author says the above integral can be normalized. How is the integral equal to a constant I could not understand that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integration over pure quantum states usually refers to the [Haar measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Haar_measure), i.e., the unitarily invariant measure.  Vaguely speaking, you assign the same volume (=weight in the integral) to any two set of states which are related by an arbitrary unitary rotation $U$. In the case of one qubit, this is equivalent to integrating over the Bloch sphere; i.e., we have that
$$
\int d\psi\, f(\psi) = \int_0^{\pi}\sin\theta d\theta \int_0^{2\pi}d\phi \, 
f(\cos(\theta/2)\vert0\rangle + e^{i\phi}\sin(\theta/2)\vert1\rangle)\ .
$$

Answer (score 2):

In general, the integral
$$ V := \int \mathrm{d} \mu = \int 1 \mathrm{d}\mu$$
is the integration of the identity over the space the measure $\mu$ is defined on, and should be intuitively understood as the *volume* of the space with respect to the measure. (This is usually only finite for compact spaces.)

Normalizing the measure means sending $\mu \mapsto \frac{1}{V}\mu$, such that the integral over the whole space is now $1$.